# Playing audio with jQuery Mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

Using HTML5 and jQuery Mobile I have a page with 3 buttons.

What I want to do is have each button select a different sound, then have another button to play the selected sound.

Can anyone give me a steer?

Thanks

Jim

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check-out the HTML5 `<audio>` tag. You can pre-load audio clips and play them when the user interacts with elements.

Docs for `<audio>`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/audio

You may want to check-out a pre-made plugin for this, I have seen JPlayer used a lot: http://jplayer.org/

Although a plugin will not be necessary, the HTML5 `<audio>` tag comes with the ability to control it using JavaScript.

Comment: Hi - sorry, not quite. I'm still a bit stuck on the actual syntax and form for doing what I want - i.e., selecting an audio file, then having playing it with another button?

Comment: To select an audio file you just set the audio file's path as the `src` attribute for the `<audio>` tag. Then to play it when you click a button you have to use the JavaScript API for `<audio>` elements. I believe that `document.getElementById('my-audio-id').play();` plays the audio file. Search Google for "audio tag javascript" which will give you tons of examples of how to programmaticly run an audio clip.

Comment: @Jimbly2 Generally when someone satisfactorily answers your question, you mark it as the accepted answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Sorry, I really don't get how I accept anything other than the first answer?